# ViewComponent vs Views vs PartialView

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am developing a .net core application and following all the new principles and techniques that have moved on from MVC5 over to MVC6 (.net core).
An area that I have questioned is the view component. The HTML helper (Html.RenderAction) has been replaced by the view component. i.e. replacing child actions with reusable components.

My main question is around using the view component correctly. I have a view that is loaded and contains 2 bootstrap tabs. When TabA is clicked I am currently loading a view component that returns a list of records. Each record row has a View / Edit button.

Once clicked I am currently loading a view component (containing a form etc) that is invoked and loaded into a modal. This is what concerns me that the invoke method is contained within the component class and the HTTP post method is contained within the controller. I don’t fully understand why they would be totally separate. I have read some benefits around separation and the fact can make testing easier. However the HTTP Post action method is in the controller.

If I was to change my design and load a normal view without a layout then I can then use the HTTPGet and HTTPPost method in 1 controller. Would changing the design to this approach be correct? Because from previous MVC versions, a partial view is loaded into the modal which would go against the concept of a view component.

Any thoughts / comments are welcome?